# PGFPlot handling all my data, do I need to pre-process the data?

Tags: pgfplots

I will be writing a report in which I analyse the performance of a piece of software. I would like to show my data using `PGFPlot`.

My plan of attack is to schedule a script to run on the machine I am using, which will run the program a number of time with a variety of parameters (the main one being the number of processors I use) and dump all the data in to a `.dat` file.

Can `PGFPlot` this? Can I ask it to average all the tests with the same parameters? I will be plotting a line graph with the average time, but I would also like to plot the standard deviation of the results.

Is `PGFPlot` the tool for this? Or should I be using `LibreOffice` to generate the relevant data, and only use `PGFPlot` at the end?

Thank you

Comment: To some extent this will depend on what you need to do. I've found it best to do everything in `pgfplots` if possible, as this allows the use of pre-built templates without the possibility of forgetting steps. However, that works at least in part because the files I have are manageable.

Comment: Doing the calculations in `pgfplots` might heavily increase the compile time. I would always recommend to save a complete dat file which does not need post-processing. Furthermore, `pgfplots` reads in fields much faster if you do not have an excess amount of columns. However, it is very dependent on the dataset size. For 200 data-points or so, it is very fast.

Comment: Thank you very much, I imagine my data will be small enough to not cause too much of an issue. Would you mind pointing me in the direction of how to average and plot SD of my samples?

Answer (score 3):

pgfplots can surely do that kind of numerics. I suppose the answer would include `pgfplotstable`. In fact, I would expect that it relies heavily on `pgfplotstable`. This, in turn, has few (if any) predefined grouping constructs which yield statistical values like the mean or the std deviation of some sample.

You would probably need to think hard, learn much of pgfplotstable, and write quite some related shared code to get what you want. The result will eventually fulfill your requirements.

So, if you have the heart of a power-user, go on - and ask specific questions on this site if you need help. But if you already have a working solution with tools which know what a mean and a standard deviation is, you will probably be better off if you generate the data with familiar tools and use pgfplots only to visualize the result. Although libreoffice does not really sound like a fully automatic solution...

I guess that it would make sense to implement such aggregate / grouping stuff into pgfplotstable. Or perhaps to write some basic layer API to access the box plot stuff of pgfplots (coming with version 1.8). But both are feature request.

Perhaps someone else has already done what I wrote in the previous paragraphs. In this case, you should probably add a sample data file, perhaps with some kind of mock output to show what you expect.